# H2 database one to zero or one declaration

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, h2, one-to-one

How I can create 1 -> 0..1 relationship in H2 using SQL command ? 
I tried with:

```
ALTER TABLE User
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (Id) 
    REFERENCES Account(UserId)
```

But it looks like it is **1 to 1** because it does not let me to add a record to user and throw exception:

```
 Referential integrity constraint violation: "CONSTRAINT_27E: PUBLIC.USER
 FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ACCOUNT(USERID) (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message you're trying to insert a record into `User` with id `3` that doesn't exist in `Account`, this is not possible, the only thing you can do is insert with `id` equal to `null`.